# Browser not responding when uploading via Azure Blob Storage

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage

I have a project where the user can upload files to a Cloud Storage and uploading large files obviously takes some time to do, which I understand. However, if the file is large enough, while the upload process to the cloud is running, the browser (Chrome in my case) will see that the webpage is not responding and give the user the option to kill the page or wait. My objective now is to do something that will not let the browser give the user the option to kill the page, essentially do something that sends signals to the client-side system and see the page as responsive, but I am struggling to find a way.

My first thought would be to add some sort of progress bar to track the upload progress whether that be through a gif, ui progress bar, or writing to the console, but all of these have failed. The screen if frozen once the upload progress begins. You can still do things in another tab, but the one that is in the middle of the upload progress is stuck and the browser sees this as the page is unresponsive, and thus asks the user whether or not they want to kill the page. The uploading is still in progress at this stage and killing the page would cancel the upload.

When I tried adding something like a loading GIF that would display before the upload method is called, it would not be displayed. However, only after the process is done is it seen for a split second since the page is setup to reload after the upload process.

When I tried the Console.WriteLine() way, nothing showed up on the console in the brower's debugger throughout the whole upload process.

The code I did for that looks something like below.

```
function CallUploadFile(fileData, successFunction, errorFunction) {
    $('#loading-gif').show()
    // Calling method where upload to Blob Storage is after showing loading gif
    $.ajax({
        url: '/File/UploadFile',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        async: true,
        success: function (fileData) { successFunction(fileData); },
        error: function (fileData) { errorFunction(fileData); },
        ...
    });
}
```

Here is what my UploadFile method looks like:

```
public async Task<string> UploadFile() {
    BlobServiceClient service = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient containter = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainer);
    BlockBlobClient block = container.GetBlockBlobClient(fileName);

    using (Stream stream = inputStream) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 50];
        int bytesRead;
        int blockNumber = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
            using (MemoryStream chunkStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead))
            {
                string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(blockNumber));
                await block.StageBlockAsync(blockId, chunkStream);
                blockNumber++;
            }
        }
        var blockList = Enumerable.Range(0, blockNumber)
            .Select(x => Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(x)))
            .ToList();
        await block.CommitBlockListAsync(blockList);
    }
    return "Success";
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here and would like some assistance.

**-MORE INFO-**

The page where I upload files is a *partial* view and is located within various view pages so uploaded files can be separated into their corresponding categories. Furthermore, the button to upload files is a Save button that can also delete files and save changes to the page all at once. This introduces complexity as now there can be multiple calls to other functions and action methods like DeleteFile() and UploadFile().

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing with the "Kill Page" notification in Chrome is likely because the browser thinks the page is unresponsive while the file upload is in progress. To prevent this and provide a better user experience, we can implement a progress bar and improve feedback during the file upload process.

The below code tracks the progress bar to track the upload progress. The progress bar will reset to zero after 10 seconds of displaying the "File Uploaded" message, and clicking on "Choose File" will also reset the progress bar to zero.

```java
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "File Upload";
}

<h2>File Upload</h2>

<form asp-controller="FileUpload" asp-action="UploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file">Select a File:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control-file">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
</form>

<div id="loading" class="text-center" style="display: none;">
    <img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading...">
</div>

<div id="progress-container" class="mt-4">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
            0%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="file-uploaded" class="alert alert-success mt-3" style="display: none;">
    File Uploaded!
</div>

<div id="error-message" class="alert alert-danger mt-3" style="display: none;">
    Error Uploading File. Please try again.
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/FileUpload/UploadFile',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                xhr: function () {
                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {
                            var percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                            $('#progress-bar').css('width', percent + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', percent);
                            $('#progress-bar').text(percent.toFixed(2) + '%');
                        }
                    });
                    return xhr;
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#loading').show();
                    $('#progress-bar').css('width', '0%').text('0%');
                    $('#file-uploaded').hide();
                    $('#error-message').hide();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // Handle success (e.g., display a success message)
                    $('#file-uploaded').show();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#progress-bar').css('width', '0%').text('0%');
                        $('#file-uploaded').hide();
                    }, 10000); // Reset after 10 seconds
                },
                error: function () {
                    // Handle error (e.g., display an error message)
                    $('#error-message').show();
                    $('#progress-bar').css('width', '0%').text('0%');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#error-message').hide();
                    }, 5000); // Hide error message after 5 seconds
                }
            });

            return false;
        });

        // Reset progress bar to zero when the "Choose File" button is clicked
        $('#file').click(function () {
            $('#progress-bar').css('width', '0%').text('0%');
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

**Controller**

```cs
 public class FileUploadController : Controller
 {
     private const string AzureStorageConnectionString = "";
     private const string ContainerName = "";

     [HttpGet]
     public IActionResult Index()
     {
         return View();
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
     {
         try
         {
             var file = Request.Form.Files[0];

             if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
             {
                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
             }

             // Create a BlobServiceClient using the connection string
             var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(AzureStorageConnectionString);

             // Get a container client
             var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(ContainerName);

             // Upload the file
             var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
             using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
             {
                 await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);
             }

             // Handle success and return a response
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             // Handle errors here
             return RedirectToAction(ex + "Index");
         }
     }
 }
```

**The loading GIF behavior to display before the upload starts:**

```java
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#file').click(function () {
            $('#progress-bar').css('width', '0%').text('0%');
            $('#file-uploaded').hide();
            $('#error-message').hide();
        });

        $('form').submit(function () {
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/FileUpload/UploadFile',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                xhr: function () {
                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {
                            var percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                            $('#progress-bar').css('width', percent + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', percent);
                            $('#progress-bar').text(percent.toFixed(2) + '%');
                        }
                    });
                    return xhr;
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#loading img').show();
                    $('#progress-container').show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#loading img').hide();
                    $('#file-uploaded').show();

                    // Reset the progress bar and messages after 10 seconds
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#progress-bar').css('width', '0%').text('0%');
                        $('#file-uploaded').hide();
                        $('#error-message').hide();
                    }, 10000);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // Handle success (e.g., display a success message)
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#error-message').show();
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

- For more details, refer to uploading [large](https://edi.wang/post/2021/7/7/upload-file-with-progress-from-browser-to-azure-blob-storage) files to [Azure](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/893/upload-big-files-aspnet-mvc-azure-storage) Blob [Storage](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/893/upload-big-files-aspnet-mvc-azure-storage) .

Comment: Thanks for responding, but there is no change when I try your solution. Chrome still sees the page as unresponsive and the progress bar does not change and is stuck at 0%. I updated my question with more details that may explain why it didn't work.

Comment: @AndrewC my progress [status](https://github.com/Sampath280/sam2/blob/main/ezgif.com-video-to-gif3.gif) in the [link](https://github.com/Sampath280/sam2/blob/main/ezgif.com-video-to-gif4.gif)

Comment: @AndrewC Refer this for deleting a [file](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/chapters/)

Comment: As I stated before, your solution does not work for me. I updated my question with more details that may or may not give you a clearer picture.

Comment: I followed this [reference](https://edi.wang/post/2021/7/7/upload-file-with-progress-from-browser-to-azure-blob-storage)      hope it helps  .